# PHP 5.3.3 bug or preg_match bad validate?

Tags: preg-match, php-5.3

```
<?php
$query = 'q=Riha47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a4744444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444na&start-index=60&max-results=20';
$pattern = "/^(?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()\[\];\/?:@&=+$,])*$/";

if (preg_match($pattern, $query))
    echo 'true';
else
    echo 'false';
```

The script has nothing as the output... It offers to download php file 0 bytes..
I need to fix it because it's probably still a bug in Zend_Gdata! Sorry for bad english.

**EDIT:**

**You have a 5.3.3 version of php?
The problem disappears if you add a "U" at the end of the expression.
What the f*ck?**

Comment: This prints "true" when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = 'q=Riha47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a47444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444a4744444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444na&start-index=60&max-results=20';

if (preg_match('#^(?:%[[:xdigit:]]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*\'()[\];/?:@&=+$,])*$#i', $query)) {
    echo "TRUE"; // THIS CASE
} else {
    echo "FALSE"
}
```